# React w/ TypeScript: why is the type for the state lost when useState with a callback as the updater

Tags: reactjs, typescript

First of all the code snippet you are going to see is a contrived example. I am just curious as to why the typing doesn't work.

```
interface MyState {
  a: boolean;
  b: number;
}

const defaultState: MyState = {
  a: false,
  b: 1
};

const keys = Object.keys(defaultState) as Array<keyof MyState>;

export default function App() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState<MyState>(defaultState);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      setMyState((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [key]: "lol". // should've given an error but it didn't
      }));
    });
  }, []);
```

so I have a `defaultState` and a list of its keys defined outside of the component. In the useEffect I am using the key to update the state(right now it is just changing every value to 'lol').  I passed a callback as the updater in the `setMyState` and what it returns should be the new state. But here I make the value to be string, which violates the interface I had `MyState`.

I wonder why it is not triggering the error

This is a live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-dewdney-u83id?file=/src/App.tsx

Minimal example without react: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmQCMB7UgGwjhAG4c9iiQBXAW2OnoF8ssFSIAM5hkpYgCsi6ALyYGuQsngUhEADQKSRAIxZu9foJHIA1hACeyOQHlJEBGAB05i0IAU4iQEoA2gAYAXXwhM0tSGDQ+AWFRLwAmaWt5PGQndK9NVN9XQKIAIgpKfP1o40oIJyKAc09JeO8gA)

Comment: Might just be a bug!

Comment: try to read variable in callBack `React.useEffect(() => { ... }, [keys])`

Comment: It seems buggy, if we use an index signature: `interface MyState {  a: boolean;  b: number;  [key: string]: number | boolean}`  ts gives an error close to what I would expect without it

Comment: Part of what's happening is that `...prev` is enough to fulfill the entire `MyState` interface, and `[key]: "lol"` is just seen as something extra.  Typescript should be able to see that you are overriding a property and making the state invalid, but it's not that smart.

Comment: Well no, because the `[key]` is overwriting the existing values in prev. If you properly type the keys and values like in my answer, you will still get a proper typing error. I adjusted my answer and CSB to use the `setMyState(prev => ({ ...prev, [key]: value }))` pattern...still shows the error correctly

Comment: Here https://catchts.com/union-array you can find an alternative for typing object keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not in using a callback to update the state - that's fine.  The issue is that when you set a property of an object using a dynamic key, typescript doesn't know what the value of the key is for any given iteration of the loop, let alone what type its value should be.  So you need to tell it. You need to dynamically type your keys using generics.  There's a great article about it [right here](https://medium.com/@vincentnewkirk/typing-dynamic-object-keys-with-ts-de0d5990a58e).

```js
  function updateValue<T extends keyof MyState, K extends MyState[T]>(
    name: T,
    value: K
  ) {
    setMyState(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      updateValue(key, "lol");
    });
  }, []);
```

#### [Here is a working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-dynamic-keys-74g8s)

#### [Working Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmQCMB7UgGwjhAG4c9iiQBXAW2OnoF8ssA3OFGSliAKyLoAvJga5CyeBQDOEADRySRACxZu9LAlIhlYZAGsIAT2XIZAeXEQEYAHSWbAClFiAlPltUKCg4KwAeD1IYNAA+AxgWEBdgY2QWAAcAEzhIADU4ChYIMIAVZAgAD0gQTNtI6NQ1ZABpcqqIGsCAbRKAXRjPTRA4NggiEo08ZEFCsZaGf2wpnztMZFcNnyau4dHeohmi5H0GXiwPZVcYUigAUUQAC08POxjZXGBo5+tfTQzsvIFIrfKxNADkFEoYN+3F+WCAA)

Gives the errors exactly as it should.

#### Further musings:

There are some interesting quirks about this.  What if you set the value to one of the possible values on your interface?

```js
keys.forEach((key) => {
 updateValue(key, 4);  // <---- no error, but there should be
});
```

In theory, this should also throw an error, because `key` could be `a`, in which case the types dont match.  TypeScript doesn't throw an error.  However, if you specify to run this only when `key === 'a'`, the error does occur:

```js
keys.forEach((key) => {
  if (key === 'a'){
    updateValue(key, 4); // <---- typechecking error occurs
  }
});
```

In the latter case, typescript is smart enough to know that if the key is `a`, the type has to be a number.  But in the former case, where you are trying to assign a value that matches one of the types on the interface, but not all of them, we may be seeing a bug in, or reaching the limits of typescript.

Comment: FYI you *can* use a function of `prevState`: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: Learn something new every day!  I'll remove that